# Auto click for next button on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I got over 3000 pages to load and i am trying to auto click on next button after the page has been loaded. The bottons looks like :
Import from page 1,... Import from page xxxx, and the link looks like : 
domainname/admin.php?page=feeds&page_no=1

Does anyone know how i can do this? I have no coding experience, i use wordpress platform.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `jQuery(document).ready()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#next").trigger('click'); // click on button once document is ready
   // or
   $("#next").click();
});
```

here i'm assuming that your button will have `id="next"` you can change it according to you needs.